A seven letter *
Here is a small rebus to solve.
The answer is a seven letter

          F 
A         G         K
  B       H       L
    C     I     M
      D   J   N
        E   O
        P   V
       R     W
      S       X
     T         Y
    I           Z 


I wonder if this shows

 Noquisi which is the Cherokee word for star and a recently named one.

 The rebus star is made from the letters of the alphabet with no 'q' (= No q) and 'u' is replaced by 'i' (= u is i).

